# Looking for a way in aframe to rotate and scale a model via touch when rendered over a marker

Tags: aframe, ar.js

I'm loading this Collada (DAE) model with aframe 0.8.2 and using aframe-ar to display it over a Hiro marker:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.2/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/1.5.5/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>
<body style='margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;'>
    <a-scene embedded arjs='trackingMethod: best; debugUIEnabled: false;'>
      <!--a-marker type='pattern' url='https://rawgit.com/germanviscuso/AR.js/master/data/data/patt.gafas'-->
      <a-marker preset='hiro'>
        <a-collada-model src="url(https://aframe.io/aframe/examples/showcase/shopping/man/man.dae)"></a-collada-model>
      </a-marker>
      <a-camera-static/>
    </a-scene>
</body>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/germanviscuso/pen/KRMgwz

I would like to know how to add controls to rotate it on its Y axis (with respect to the marker) by using swipe gestures on a mobile phone browser and to scale the model dynamically when doing pinch gestures. Ideally it would be nice if it also works with the mouse/touchpad when I'm testing in my laptop but touch on the phone is enough.

Can universal-controls handle this? Any example that I can see? This has to work while the model is being rendered dynamically with respect to the marker (AR tracking).

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't use the "native" controls based off raycaststers. Instead I would use any js gesture detection library. In this example i used [hammer.js](https://hammerjs.github.io/).

hammer.js registers an object which emits events when `pan`, `swipe`, `pinch` gestures are detected. I've created the object with the listeners in an a-frame component.

1. When `pan` is detected i just rotate the model depending on the direction (2 - left, 4 - right, 8 - up, 16 - down)
2. When `pinch` is detected i change the scale, depending on the event value, you can multiply by any factor. The component is below:

   AFRAME.registerComponent("foo",{
   init:function() {
   var element = document.querySelector('body');
   this.marker = document.querySelector('a-marker')
   var model = document.querySelector('a-collada-model');
   var hammertime = new Hammer(element);
   var pinch = new Hammer.Pinch(); // Pinch is not by default in the recognisers
   hammertime.add(pinch); // add it to the Manager instance

   ```
      hammertime.on('pan', (ev) => {
        let rotation = model.getAttribute("rotation")
        switch(ev.direction) {
          case 2:
            rotation.y = rotation.y + 4
            break;
          case 4:
            rotation.y = rotation.y - 4
            break;
          case 8:
            rotation.x = rotation.x + 4
            break;
          case 16:
            rotation.x = rotation.x - 4
            break;
          default:
            break;
        }
        model.setAttribute("rotation", rotation)
      });

     hammertime.on("pinch", (ev) => {
        let scale = {x:ev.scale, y:ev.scale, z:ev.scale}
        model.setAttribute("scale", scale);
    });
   ```

   }
   });

<s>Working glitch [here](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/oil-seeker?path=index.html:17:6). In my example i also check if the marker is visible, thought it could be convinient.</s>

Working example [here](https://gftruj.github.io/webzamples/ar/arjs_rotate_zoom.html)

Comment: Hi , can you please recreate the Project as it was deleted from Glitch ?

Comment: @HamoudaArfaoui thanks for letting me know, I'll try to update the anwser somewhere near the weekend.

Comment: could  you please check the project? looks like it's not accessible now

Comment: Yes, sadly still not accessible

Comment: Updated the answer with a working example

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you! (I'm using on an `entity`, not a model, so I adapted code to use `this.el.object3D....` and it works great.)