# Scaling of 3d model on marker in a-frame

Tags: three.js, aframe, marker

I am loading 3d model on marker using a-frame. I want to know how I can do the dynamic scaling of a 3d model like when 3d model appears on marker how I can **zoom in and out** the 3d model.
Please help me with this.

Comment: let me know if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50197836/looking-for-a-way-in-aframe-to-rotate-and-scale-a-model-via-touch-when-rendered) helps

Comment: I am afraid not.

Comment: I tried but its not working can u please suggest another in a-frame

Comment: Please provide a code example and show what you have tried so far. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to get more adequate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can zoom in / out the 3d model by setting the `scale` attribute.
Having your model within a reference `let model = document.querySelector("#model"):`

```
 model.setAttribute("scale", "2 2 2")
```

will enlarge it.

```
 model.setAttribute("scale", "0.5 0.5 0.5")
```

will make it smaller.

---

You can connect it with a mouse scroll, or any other event with `addEventListener` and change the scale according to the readings.

**MouseWheel example:**

```
window.addEventListener("wheel", (e) => {
    let scaleFactor = e.deltaY > 0 ? 0.9 : 1.1  //check if we scroll up, or down
    let scale = this.el.getAttribute("scale").clone() // clone the scale vector
    scale.multiplyScalar(scaleFactor)                 
    this.el.setAttribute("scale", scale)              // apply new scale
  })
```

live fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/gez2fxk9/8/).

Comment: thanks Adam , It worked 
One little help different gltf models have different scaling ,can I set the scaling before and then zooming option works.
For eg:
<a-gltf-model drag-rotate-component  src="#object4" scale="20 20 20"></a-gltf-model> ---- it will show proper layout on marker 
After using zoom option , 3d object coming too small ,then after zooming i am able to see .
Is there any way I can set initial scale and then I can do zooming

Comment: You can set the scale like you did in the comment, but the initial size pretty much depends on the model size, as set in blender or maya

Comment: When i set the scale I am unable to zoom .

Comment: Does it work in mobile also,like if i am scanning pattern from mobile ,with my touch it will zoom????

Comment: No ,I tried !! than i tried with another approach of adding event listener of touchmove  and touchend which works for me.